# Connect timeout and retry, what happens with old request?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, network-programming, python-requests

What if I send off a GET/POST request and I get hit by a Connect timeout (not read timeout) and retry the request after?

Will the old request be cancled also on the server or will it maybe still arrive at the server at a later time and executed on server?

Also if we do not get hit by connect timeout but to get the response just takes longer it should mean the request arrived at the server but is probably still being executed on the server right? So we should wait until response is recieved since we etablished the connection for sure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because of how TCP works, if you get a *connection* timeout then the server didn't even receive your request.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so if the timeout in my script gets hit, the old request would be "cancled" and not still tried to be sent to the server?

Comment: If it has timed out then the network stack would have already tried and retried a number of times to get a reply from the other end. TCP is *reliable*, if you get an error then it's almost always fatal (for the connection) and you should disconnect and try connecting again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also the same if its a user set timeout? Like for example after 4 seconds (set by user on requests library) the connection times out would it be safe then to send the request again without making like duplicate requests?

Comment: If the timeout is not a TCP timeout, but something implemented at a higher level, then no it's not the same thing.